# http_build_query putting strange chars in query string

Tags: php, character-encoding, query-string

I'm using `cURL` to submit a form and to do that I'm using PHP's `http_build_query()` to form a query string. I was wondering why the form didn't submit and then I echoed out the query string only to find a '¶' and a 'ð` in the query string.

```
$post_data = array('terms' => 'true', 
                  'ethnicity' => 0,
                  'param0' => 'Lance',
                  'param1' => 'Newman');
$post_data = http_build_query($post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

echo $post_data;
```

Returns

```
terms=trueðnicity=0¶m0=Lance¶m1=Newman
```

I tried putting

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the top of the page with no luck

Comment: the php file it's also saved as UTF8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character sequences `&eth` and `&para` are being interpreted by your browser as malformed character escape sequences (`&eth;` for ð and `&para;` for ¶).

If you want to print the query in an HTML document, run it through `htmlspecialchars()` first.