# Why doesn't http_build_query work correctly?

Tags: php, url

Here is my code:

```
print_r(http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("param3"=>"baz"))));
```

And here is the result:

```
o=newest&u=true¶m3=baz
```

Well what's `¶`? Why sometimes `http_build_query` doesn't put `&` between parameters?

---

And here is the result without `http_build_query`:

```
Array ( [o] => newest [u] => true [param3] => baz )
```

Comment: What are the contents of $_GET

Comment: What do you get if you urldecode the http_build_query result?

Comment: @mkaatman `o=newest&u=true¶m3=baz`

Comment: I change the name `param3` and the strange symbol seems to disapear. o=newest&u=1&prm=baz

Comment: @heliosk . . . Odd!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http\_build\_query putting strange chars in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589875/http-build-query-putting-strange-chars-in-query-string)

Answer (score 1):

So the representation of `¶` is `& p a r a ;`(html entity), when you use that name `param3` it is interpreted to that symbol `¶` (Pilcrow Sign). That's why you see `¶m3=baz`

Comment: Wow nice job. I didn't see that at all.